# How to move repo one level up by github action

Tags: github, github-actions

I am running self hosted runner to get the code from my etl repo, but the folder structure in my local looks like. Not sure the etl folder comes from. I try the `mv`, but it does not work. Please help thank you

```
_work
├── etl
│   └── etl
│       ├── abc
```

what I want and also is the folder structure in the repo.

```
_work
├── etl
│    ├── abc
```

Comment: The fist level that is created is always the name of the repository, no way to change that. The second one is then the name of the folder in the repo you have created.

Comment: @RobBos thank you for the explanation. Is there any way to move multiple repo in one folder?